# Python write output into a txt file and read from a txt file

Tags: python

Hi I am trying to call the write function in a loop(basically, the write() function will be run several times)

What I wrote for the write is something like:

```
w.write(board+" "+str(number))
```

here board is a string(16 chars) and number is an int. I didn't add in any newline and w is to write to a txt file.

So what I want is the output follows one another with no newline inserted. However, when I output the solution, in the text file, the output will be shifted to a newline.

May I know if there is any inner issue regarding the write() function, is there anyway I could solve it?

```
def countword(board,dic):
list=[0]*26
for char in board:
    if char == '\n':
        break
    list[ord(char)-97]+=1
number=0
notFound=False
for word in range(0,(len(dic)-1)):
    for i in range(26):
        if (list[i]<dic[word][i]):
            notFound=True
            break
    if notFound==True:
        notFound=False
        continue
    number+=1;
return number



def dict(dictionary):

result=[]
s=open(dictionary,'r')
lines=s.readlines()         
for line in lines:
    if len(line)<3:
        continue
    list=[0]*26
    line=line.lower()
    for char in line:
        if str(char).isalpha():
            list[ord(char)-97]+=1
    result.append(list)
s.close()
return result

f = open('input.txt', 'r')
w = open('output.txt','w')


dic=dict('word_dictionary')
while True:
    board=f.read(16)
    if len(board)<16:
        print("End of file!")
        break
    print (board)
    number=countword(board,dic)

    w.write(board+" "+str(number))
f.close()
w.close()
```

In fact, when I read from the file, I also encounter a problem:
when I read them using simple

```
board=f.read(16)
print(board)
board=f.read(16)
print(board)
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code here so that it can be debugged more easily?

Comment: @Anderson Green Thank you for your reply! I just added it.

Comment: What is the shape of input.txt? You could be reading the new line character in f.read(16)

Comment: Post the code where you are writing to the file. file.write() does not add a newline unless told to do so, or if your strings contain new lines.

Comment: Sorry about that, I find that because the file has \n at the end of each line instead of \r\n so it doesn't appear to be a newline in text reader of windows.

Comment: `dict` is already a standard Python function. Won't you run into trouble trying to define your own function called `dict`?